# How can I repair an external HDD with faulty powering?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hardware-failure, power

I just moved into a new place, but unfortunately mixed up the power cables for my [Seagate 4GB Backup Plus](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HFRWXQ0) and a speaker system. Upon move in I inadvertently used the speaker power cable for my HDD.

Since I do not regularly use this external drive (except for backing up certain data), I did not notice my mistake until about a week later, when I realized the drive was **not being detected and the indicator light was blinking rapidly**.

I quickly realized the issue and swapped the power cables, but at this point, it would seem the device has been permanently damaged.

What I've tried:

- Installing newest drivers
- Detecting new hardware changes in the device manager
- Removing the external drive housing and installing the drive directly into the PC, which resulted in a "driver power state failure" blue screen upon attempting to detect storage devices.

Are there any other common methods that could potentially save this drive?

What recovery options are there for saving the data on this drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you overvolted the drive (applied a larger-than-required voltage and damaged it), but its very likely you've damaged only the controller, and not the physical drive/platters. This means that you just need to replace the PCB with an identical one, so that you can power up and retrieve the data from it.

Identical PCBs can be found on other donor drives, and quite often data recovery services will have good PCBs that they can swap in. If you manage to get a hold of one yourself, you might be able to swap it out yourself too. However, if you have no or very little experience, you may end up making it worse by trying the repair on your own. I recommend getting quotes from different data recovery services, and they might give you a discount if they don't need to go into the drive completely, if just to replace the controller board on it.

Comment: Before spending any money, and since disassembly would be required to replace the controller anyways, removing the drive from the enclosure (although that could be destructive to the case itself) and hooking it through a SATA to USB device might be in order.  However, there are some enclosures that do some strange things with sector size, so while the drive might be detected the file system might not be.

Comment: Yes, this seems very likely as the voltage for the speaker power cable is almost double the external drive's power cable.

Comment: @Ramhound, If he could detect the drive and read raw data from it, it would at least be a start. OP could, in theory, read all the raw bits into an image file and later on try different sector sizes to see if the data would be readable. I'm not sure how to practically go about this, but there might be programs out there that automatically detect sector sizes based on patterns, perhaps.